# Update label when returning from background

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel

I have a problem trying to update the label when the app returns from Background. I already implemented LocalNotifications for my timer app and is working perfect but when I return to the app the countdown label is stopped. 
So basically I am trying to find the way to update the countdown label with the current time left. I would appreciate any help!

My Code is here:

```
    var timer = Timer()
    var teas = Teas()
    var isTimerRunning = false
    var alarmSound = AVAudioPlayer()
    var playing = false
    var initialValueOfTime = 0


    var timeDuration = 0
    var currentBackgroundDate = Date()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(teasGoBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(runTimer), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

    }



@objc func runTimer() {


        if isTimerRunning {
            teas.time -= 1
            let difference = Date().timeIntervalSince(self.currentBackgroundDate)
            timeDuration = timeDuration + Int(difference)

            if teas.time <= 0 {
                timer.invalidate()
                startButton.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
            }
        }
        else {
            teas.time = initialValueOfTime
        }

 @objc func resetTimer() {

        timer.invalidate()
        runTimer()

    }

    @objc func teasGoBackground() {
           timer.invalidate()
           currentBackgroundDate = Date()
       }


  @IBAction func startButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {


        if !isTimerRunning {
            navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
            isTimerRunning = true
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            print("time")
            startButton.setTitle("Stop Brewing", for: .normal)
        } else {
            navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false
            isTimerRunning = false
            resetTimer()
            startButton.setTitle("Start Brewing", for: .normal)
        }


    }
```

Comment: you need to add your observers inside `viewDidLoad()` event, not in `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your observers inside `viewDidLoad()`, **NOT** in `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(teasGoBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(runTimer), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

}
```

Comment: It will be the same, because when I return to the app the countdown label stopped

Comment: So basically I need to find the way to update the label from the second that the user left to the background and resume the countdown. Any idea how can I approach this?

Comment: Save the time in UserDefaults when app enters background,
Then save another time in UserDefaults when app comes back to foreground,
Subtract the reopened (foreground time) from the background time. You'll have a time it stayed in background. Now add that time to the counter when it entered background.

Comment: Could you share a small example? I am a very new developer and still struggling with it... would really appreciate that! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I implemented this code to my project and worked!

```
if let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "teastart\(teas.id)") as? Date {
                let now = Date()
                let secondsTillNow = now.timeIntervalSince1970
                let previousSeconds = date.timeIntervalSince1970
                let timeSinceStart = secondsTillNow - previousSeconds
                let time = Int(timeSinceStart)
                if time > teas.time {
                    initialValueOfTime = teas.time

                    startButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Start Brewing", comment: ""), for: .normal)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "timerunning\(teas.id)")
                } else {
                    initialValueOfTime = teas.time - time

                    startButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Stop Brewing", comment: ""), for: .normal)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "timerunning\(teas.id)")
                }
            } else {
                initialValueOfTime = teas.time
                UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "timerunning\(teas.id)")
            }
```